# Gridview within a TabBarview that moves a sliver app bar

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I was wondering it is possible to have a grid view within a tabbarview which has properties of a sliver so it moves the app bar.

> I have a grid view within a tabbarview however it does not cause the tab bar to collapse

This is my code so far

```
NestedScrollView(
  headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
    return SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      floating: true,
      pinned: false,
      stretch: false,
      snap: false,
        (...)///Collapsible space etc
    );
  }, 
  body: TabBarView(
      children: [
        ///Other widgets
        (...)

        ///My gridview
        GridView(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2),
          children: List.generate(10, (index) {
            return Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.pink,
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
          }),
        )
      ]
  )
)
```

> Edit Below

[EDIT]

1. Set shrinkWrap to true
2. Sets physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `shrinkWrap` to `true` and `physics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to your `GridView`. 
This is useful when you add a scrollable widget inside another scrollable widget.